# Requirements Gathering Form?

Tags: web-development, customer-service

Do you use a standard form to gather requirements from a customer prior to making a website?  If so what are the questions you ask?

**For example**

Purpose of Website: (sell products, reduce number of enquires, reduce work load, etc)

Do you have you’re an existing logo? (can you send it via email)

Do you have a preferred font for the website text?

Do you have a colour theme for your logo, business cards, shop you would like to keep on the website

Do you have photos you can provide of your Products?

etc

Ofcause it would need to be tweaked slightly for each customer but I was looking for a generic document as a baseline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree. I think the personal approach is the best option but with larger enterprise scale projects a more structured approach may be required. This article contains all of the best resources I have seen on the web about requirements gathering:

http://qwertyphilia.com/2008/11/requirements-gathering-for-web-projects/

Comment: Thanks this link http://www.mountevansdesigns.com/worksheets.html is what I was after, just a checklist to make sure I do not forget anything when I talk with the client.

Comment: Glad to help =)

Answer (score 4):

Well, generally no, I don't. Websites are often complex tasks, so I prefer to develop a personal relationship with the client.

Instead of robotically gathering the information that's needed (nothing's *wrong* with that, really), I find out where this person or company is coming from, what their vision is, and how they really feel about this project. I talk with them -- if not in person, then on the phone or by video chat -- and I try to approach each project as if I was a dedicated member of their team or if I was that individual's committed partner.

A little bit of sacrifice on your part goes a long way, and besides, the non-necessity of details right up front will attract more customers and give you an excuse to communicate often with your clients. Release early; release often.